# How to use a viewmodel to display data in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and would like to display data from two models in a view in table form.
this is my Customer model:

```
 public class Customer


      {
            public int CustomerID { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "First Name")]

            public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }

                [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Display(Name = "Street")]
            public string CustomerAddress1 { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Display(Name = "Suburb")]
            public string CustomerAddress2 { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Display(Name = "City")]
            public string CustomerAddress3 { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            [Display(Name = "Postal code")]
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [StringLength(10)]
            [Display(Name = "Cellphone Number")]
            public string CustomerCell { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
            public string FullName
            {
                get { return CustomerFirstName + " " + CustomerLastName; }
            }

            public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

this is my Hire model:

```
 public class Hire
    {
        public int HireID { get; set; }

         [Display(Name = "Equipment type")]
        public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
        public int PurchaseID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Returned date")]
        public DateTime? ReturnedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual Purchase Purchases { get; set; }
        public virtual Equipment Equipments { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class Custhire



     {

            public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }


            public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }


            public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

            public string CustomerCell { get; set; }

            public int HireID { get; set; }

            public DateTime? ReturnedDate { get; set; }


        }
```

This is my controller I use to pass the view model to the view:

```
     public ActionResult Table()
            {
                Custhire model = new Custhire();
                return View(model);
            }
```

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<FCproject.ViewModel.Custhire>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Table";
}

<h2>Table</h2>

<table class="table table-condensed"
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CustomerID</th>
            <th>Equipment</th>
            <th>Retrned date</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <body>
        @foreach (var item in ViewModel.Custhire)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CustomerFirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CustomerLastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CustomerEmail)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CustomerCell)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.HireID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ReturnedDate)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </body>
    <tr>
</table>
```

in my view, my `@foreach` says `ViewModel` does not exist in current context

Comment: It need to be `@foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: But you don't appear o have shown the correct controller method anyway - the one you have shown return a single `Custhire` object but your view is  `@model IEnumerable<Custhire>` which would throw an exception.

Comment: How would I pass a multiple Custhire to the view?

Comment: I am trying to make a table to display each customers information and its corresponding hire id and returneddate

Comment: `var model = new List<Custhire>{ new Custhire(), new Custhire() }; return View(model);` would return a collection of 2 default `Custhire` objects. But I assume you want to populate them with actual data from a database?

Comment: yes, I want to populate from an actual database

Comment: Then you need to write a query. Have a go and if your having problems, post a new question.

Comment: The Viewmodel does not exist because you haven´t declared it on the server.  What if you declare it --> ViewModel.Custhire = Model.GetList();

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things to check for -

You have bind your view with -

```
IEnumerable<FCproject.ViewModel.Custhire>
```

And the `Controller` snippet that you have provided returns, single Custhire object. Which actually should return `IEnumerable` of `Custhire` Something for example like -

```
    public ActionResult Table()
    {
        List<Custhire> model = new List<Custhire>();

        //keep adding the "Custhire" to the collection
        //as per your requirement
        model.Add(new Custhire());

        return View(model);
    }
```

Second, you need to replace,

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewModel.Custhire)
```

with this

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
```

as the `Model` itself contains collection of Custhire.

Answer (score 0):

When you create view, ensure that is `strongly typed`

[image]